# What's the question title doing over there?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image: title]

Probably from a change to `all.css`, which seems to have just changed 20 minutes ago?

```
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jun 2013 02:19:21 GMT
```

Comment: It's also occurring on [su], so I [already posted this to mSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185720/189912).

Comment: [CSS bug fixed at 10:37 UTC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185774/204574)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this to dev. It will be on live server shortly.

Comment: Whilst you're about, any chance you can cast your eye over [this lot](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/tagged/design) some of which have been outstanding for years - cheers.